# Fuzzy fix column based correct values in a list

Tags: python, nlp, data-cleaning, matching, fuzzy

I have a dirty dataframe as shown below

| Region |
| --- |
| Berlin |
| Munich |
| Berlin-Spandau |
| Spandau-Berlin |
| Shop-Munich |
| munich-rest |
| Frankfurt |

I also have list with the clean information

city = ['Berlin','Munich','Frankfurt']

I need help creating a new column in the data frame with clean cities as shown

| Region | Clean Region |
| --- | --- |
| Berlin | Berlin |
| Munich | Munich |
| Berlin-Spandau | Berlin |
| Spandau-Berlin | Berlin |
| Shop-Munich | Munich |
| munich-rest | Munich |
| Frankfurt-pla | Frankfurt |

I am not sure how to create this column. Need help in python

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda function.

```
city = ["Munich", "Berlin"]
def func(x):
    for k in city:
        if k.lower() in x.lower():
            return k
    return x
df["Clean Region"] = df['Region'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Comment: Getting an error, list index out of range

Comment: fixed it. try again. it was because there is a row which item doesn't contain city string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you start from a list of cities, you could first use `.str.contains` to find which city is included in each cell:

```
>>> cities = ["Berlin", "Munich", "Frankfurt"]
>>> for city in cities:
        df[city] = df["Region"].str.lower().str.contains(city.lower())

>>> df
           Region  Berlin  Munich  Frankfurt
0          Berlin    True   False      False
1          Munich   False    True      False
2  Berlin-Spandau    True   False      False
3  Spandau-Berlin    True   False      False
4     Shop-Munich   False    True      False
5     munich-rest   False    True      False
6       Frankfurt   False   False       True
```

Now, you can use `.melt` and then `.loc` to transform those `True` values into a string and then select only those rows:

```
>>> df = df.melt(id_vars=["Region"], value_vars=["Berlin", "Munich", "Frankfurt"], var_name="Clean Region")
>>> df = df.loc[x["value"], ["Region", "Clean Region"]]
>>> df
        Region Clean Region
0           Berlin       Berlin
2   Berlin-Spandau       Berlin
3   Spandau-Berlin       Berlin
8           Munich       Munich
11     Shop-Munich       Munich
12     munich-rest       Munich
20       Frankfurt    Frankfurt
```